# Декодировать строку в utf-8 или автоопределение кодировки при загрузке / javascript

Tags: javascript, кодировка

У меня дропзона в которую загружают csv, кодировка та, которую я укажу в reader.readAsText(file) 2-м параметром.
Можно ли как-то автоопределять, что за кодировка попадает и в зависимости от это указывать 2-й параметр?
Или, если нет, то как перевести строку из cp1251 в utf-8?
Пробовал через TextDecoder и TextEncoder, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693400/converting-from-windows-1251-to-utf-8-in-node-js) подсказывают такое решение:

```
body = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
conv = new iconv.Iconv('windows-1251', 'utf8');
body = conv.convert(body).toString();
```